# Object in ProjectReference not accessible when using 'Import'

Tags: c#, namespaces

In a simple project i want to reference objects from a webreference added to another c# library.

The Webreference is called `QServices` The `default namespace` is set as below
[image]

What seems to work is the following code:

```
Taskworkflow.SI.QServices.Record[] querysResult = new Taskworkflow.SI.QServices.Record[0];
```

yet when i import the `Taskworkflow.SI` - namespace, i keep on getting errors:

```
using TaskWorkflow.SI;
....

QServices.Record[] querysResult = new QServices.Record[0];
```

This results in the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'QServices' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Could someone clarify this for me?
Thank you for your time.

**Note:** `QServices` do only exist inside `TaskWorkflow.SI`. They do not have any occurences in other projects nor do they have any classes/namespaces/objects that share the name.

Comment: It sounds like `TaskWorkflow.SI.QServices` is a namespace, not a type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect that for whatever reason, you're ending up with a *namespace* called `QServices` declared in the `TaskWorkflow.SI` namespace. So actually you want:

```
using TaskWorkflow.SI.QServices;
....

Record[] querysResult = new Record[0];
```

Or you *could* explicitly alias it:

```
using QServices = TaskWorkflow.SI.QServices;
....

QServices.Record[] querysResult = new QServices.Record[0];
```

Comment: Ow Nice! I wasn't aware there was a possibility to use aliases on namespaces. Thank you for this new insight! This will actually help me alot in the future.